# How navigate to next page using AJAX in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't have so much experience using AJAX in a MVC application, in fact is my first facing. Please check the below image and note the rectangles.

[image]

The image is just an example that I took from internet.

The biggest rectangle is a partial view in my application and I have to render it when the user press Continue or Continuar button. The application should replace the current view for another without refresh the page.

This is the code which I'm testing, note first that I'm passing the first element of a list, but when the user press the button, render the view with the next element index = 2.

```
    public ActionResult DoTest()
    {

        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        { }

        List<Worksheet> worksheets = new List<Worksheet>()
        {
            new Worksheet("Hoja 1", ...),
            new Worksheet("Hoja 2", ...)
        };
        return View(worksheets[0]);
    }
```

Can orient me a little bit to know how to implement this feature? I just know that I need to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look through the tutorials and examples [here](http://awesome.codeplex.com/). There's plenty of other material around on the web with information on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you can achieve this. One way would be to write a custom paging Helper (HtmlHelper) that accepts new content upon the post event. You can view all about Helpers here : [Custom HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Another way could be to use partial page rendering to achieve the partial page update upon post event.

If I was you I would combine a partial view with a jquery function to update the content. You can view some help on that here: [Change dive content with Jquery](http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/change-div-content-with-jquery.html)